# Pyinstaller 3.1.1 no --exclude-module option

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyinstaller, pyqt5

I have a little problem with pyinstaller, version 3.1.1. I'm using it with python 3.4 (Anaconda).
I need to compile a project excluding PyQt5 and matplotlib

```
pyinstaller --onefile --icon=Project.ico --exclude-module=PyQt5 --exclude-module=matplotlib Project.py
```

but when I try to use "--exclude-module" I get the following error message:

```
Usage: pyinstaller-script.py [opts] <scriptname> [ <scriptname> ...] | <specfile>
pyinstaller-script.py: error: no such option: --exclude-module
```

Did I make a mistake in writing the command?

Any help is welcome.

EDIT:
The problem was the version of pyinstaller I was using. I donwloaded the development branche from github. Now I installed the stable version from pyinstaller.org and everything is working fine... At least for the --exclude-module instruction.

Comment: There's no option called `--exclude-module` in PyInstaller.

Comment: @linusg it's [documented](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#general-options) as existing..